# Xcode UILabel in GridView only updating every OTHER load

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is the strangest behavior I've ever witnessed, I have some simple code I've used in many other situations, but for some reason, it's only updating on even attempts

You pick a type, it sets, then the text clears, then it sets, I can't figure it out:

I'm using the following code:

```
- (void) CalculateDueDate
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        NewBid.BidJobTypeId, @"typeId",  nil];

[appDelegate.globalObjectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/bid/GetDueDate" parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    dueDate = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0];
    NewBid.RequestDueDate = [CommonUtils GetDateFromString:dueDate.Description];


    // need to debug, loading twice and inconsistent
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    //[self.tableView reloadData];

    // need more debug , not loading, flashing once blank once good, firing events multiple times, something wrong, maybe claculate inside of cellforindexpath not good idea
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}];
```

}

Here is a video I took of the behavior:  http://youtu.be/XIdg1W81hgA

What I want to happen is when a selection is made for job type, it's supposed to calculate a date async, then just set the label in the grid, I've done it hundreds of times but for some reason this grid is just not working, any ideas??

Also here is the custom delegate I wrote from the selector

```
- (void) madeGenericSelection:(GenericSelectorViewController *)viewController didChooseItem:(GenericItem *)item selectedRow:(NSNumber *)row
{


switch ([row intValue]) {
    case 1:
        NewBid.BidJobTypeId = item.Id;
        [self CalculateDueDate];
        break;
    case 2:
        NewBid.BidSalutationId = item.Id;
        break;
    case 5:
        NewBid.BidTextId = item.Id;
        break;


}

//reload the grid no matter what changed
[_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `success` callback is executed on the main thread? Hint: You can use `[NSThread isMainThread]` to checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I did throw that in there, and MainThread is "YES", so I don't think that's it....  but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

How about forcing it to execute on main tread like :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //Do what you need to update the UI

});
```

Comment: Can I do that with async RestKit calls?   Where would I plug that into the calculation routine?  since it's already asynchronous....

Comment: Hi Brandon, what I did was,  I used dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() to manage to update my UI as soon as I want, because there were a case that I want to update my UI according to server response, but UI didn't update as soon as I got the response, so I kind of force it to execute UI update using this dispatch_async on the main thread. What you can do is :

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

});